# How do I sort a list alphabetically and numerically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my scenario

```html
<selectclass="form-control" id="my_select"><optionvalue="0">List is Number</option><option value="1">List is Alphabetical</option></select>

  <liclass="ui-state-default " ng-repeat="damageResult in damageResultList>  <span>{{damageResult.damageMechanismList}}hfgh</span></li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Apply `orderBy` filter on that field. You can learn more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) about sorting.

```
ng-repeat="damageResult in damageResultList | orderBy:'YOUR_FIELD_NAME'"
```

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is define a custom function to sort and convert the text to number in case field is number

```
$scope.sorterFunc = function(entity){
    return $scope.isFieldNumber? parseInt(entity[$scope.property], 10) : entity[$scope.property];
};
```

and then in ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="entity in entityArray | orderBy:sorterFunc ">
```